# Obter elemento responsável pelo erro

Tags: javascript, html

Existe a possibilidade de saber qual é o elemento no HTML responsável pela ação causadora do erro em JavaScript?

código:

```
<button onclick="a(this);">GO!</button>
<script>
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  console.log(error.stack); // event.target = window
}
</script>
```

Saída:

> ReferenceError: a is not defined
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (onerror.html:1)

Nesta referencia "HTMLButtonElement.onclick" diz que é um button e que foi no evento onclick, porém no mesmo momento não diz nada, não estou conseguindo selecionar de alguma maneira este elemento, ou será que desta forma, usando o `stack` não é possível? Teria outra maneira de "chegar" neste elemento?

```
var domID = "HTMLButtonElement".id;
addObjLog(document.querySelector(domID)); //exemplo de uso
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: a is not defined` - Aqui está dizendo que a função `a` não está definida, ou seja, ela não existe no contexto que você a está chamando.

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior não é bem isso, o erro é proposital, para acionar o evento do onerror, a ideia seria saber que foi o botão que fez o erro através deste evento

Comment: Ah, ok. Entendi. =/

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é apanhando a excepção e voltar a lança-la com um identificador do elemento que causou o erro.

```
<button id="btn" onclick="try{a(this);}catch(err){throw new Error(event.target.id)}">
    GO!
</button>
<script>
    window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
</script>
```